# Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, differentiable. Suppose that $f'(x) ≥ 1$, for all $x > 0$. Show that $f'(0) ≥ 1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, differentiable. Suppose that $f'(x) ≥ 1$, for all $x > 0$. Show that $f'(0) ≥ 1$

I am quite lost. I was thinking that this is insinuating I am dealing with a continuous function, but I don't know how to use this to show that $f'(0) ≥ 1$

Comment: $f'$ need not be continuous. Think of the mean value theorem to prove the assertion.

Comment: @DanielFischer The first thing I thought of was Darboux, but I think your approach is simpler. You might want to add a short answer below.

Comment: If $f'(x)$ is not continuous at some point, then the discontinuity is essential, i.e. there are not jump discontinuities for $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 5):

While $f^{\prime}$ may not be continuous, by [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) it has the intermediate value property.

Hence if $f^{\prime}(0)=a<1$, and $f^{\prime}(1)=b\geq 1$, then for all $a<c<b$ there exists some $x_0\in (0,1)$ such that $f^{\prime}(x_0)=c$. Since $a<1$ we can choose $c<1$ to obtain $f^{\prime}(x_0)<1$, contrary to the hypothesis.

Comment: ahh I see it now. This is a nice theorem

Answer (score 3):

If you need a more elementary (say direct) proof,  suppose $f'(0)<1$ and wlog $f(0)=0$. Then there is $\theta<1$ and a sequence $x_n\rightarrow 0^+$ so that $f(x_n)\leq \theta x_n$. But then for $m>n$ large enough 
$$ \frac{f(x_n)-f(x_m)}{x_n-x_m} \leq \theta \frac{x_n}{x_n-x_m} <1$$
which implies by the usual MVT that there is $\xi\in (x_m,x_n)$ so that $f'(\xi)<1$.